# Python BeautifulSoup - Extracting <b> tag text into array

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to extract the text of the b tag within one specific class (of which there are multiple instances) into an array. I am doing this with `BeautifulSoup 4` and `Python 3`.

I am trying to webscrape [this](https://www.amazon.ca/Abba-Moisture-Conditioner-Unisex-33-8-Ounce/dp/B000VZS3VW/ref=sr_1_1/145-7226897-1893421?ie=UTF8&qid=1532712550&sr=8-1&keywords=B000VZS3VW) page. This is what my code looks like at the moment.

```
def cattest():
    subcat = soup.find_all('span', {"class": "zg_hrsr_ladder"})[x].findChildren()
    for i, child in enumerate(subcat):
        categories = child.text
        print(categories)

for x in range(0, len(cat)):
    cattest()
```

This results in the following output:

```
Beauty & Personal Care
Hair Care
Hair Care Products
Conditioners
Conditioners
Beauty & Personal Care
Personal Care
Personal Care
```

What I would like to do is get the text from the b tags of the `zg_hrsr_ladder` element and put them into an array. The expected result would then be:

```
[Conditioners, Personal Care]
```

Any assistance on how I might achieve this would be very helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension and add `'b'` to the arguments of `findChildren`

```
In [59]: [element.text for s in soup.find_all('span', {"class": "zg_hrsr_ladder"}) for element in s.findChildren('b')]
Out[59]: ['Conditioners', 'Personal Care']
```

This would be the equivalent of

```
In [63]: res = []

In [64]: for s in soup.find_all('span', {"class": "zg_hrsr_ladder"}):
    ...:     for element in s.findChildren('b'):
    ...:         res.append(element.text)
    ...:

In [65]: res
Out[65]: ['Conditioners', 'Personal Care']
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exactly what I was looking for. Your help is very much appreciated.

Comment: no problem. please accept the answer and upvote if that's the case

Comment: Not sure who downvoted, but my upvote isn't resetting it to 0 for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Number of ways you can do that. Here are two of them. Pick either of the two:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = "https://www.amazon.ca/Abba-Moisture-Conditioner-Unisex-33-8-Ounce/dp/B000VZS3VW/ref=sr_1_1/145-7226897-1893421?ie=UTF8&qid=1532712550&sr=8-1&keywords=B000VZS3VW"

res = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")

#using .find_next()
subcat = [item.find_next("b").text for item in soup.find_all('span', class_='zg_hrsr_ladder')]
print(subcat)

#using selector
subcat = [item.text for item in soup.select('span.zg_hrsr_ladder > b')]
print(subcat)
```

They both yield same results:

```
['Conditioners', 'Personal Care']
```